# Django: how to implement form in a sidebar?

Tags: django, forms, validation

EDIT2

OK, I did not pass POST data in context. Now sidebar form display errors... but still redirected to patient_form.html

[image]

context_processors.py

```
f request.user.is_authenticated:
     context['patient_form'] = PatientForm(request.POST)
```

---

EDIT

template with error is displayed but I would like form in sidebar displayed the rrors...

[image]

---

I am trying to implemen a form (PatientForm form and PatientCreate view) in a sidebar using CBV.
But it doesn't works until now...

I pass my form in context using context_processor.

And PatientForm is displayed in sidebar but when I submit data are neither registered (if valid) nor errors messages are displayed (if not valid).

I have tried like mentionned in this post [Django sidebar form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032264/django-sidebar-form) . Data are registered but I do not mange to display errors...

base.py

```
...
<nav class="navbar col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
...
    <form id="id-form" method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ patient_form | crispy }}
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" type="submit">Create</button>
    </form>
...
</nav>
```

views.py

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")
class PatientCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView): 

    model = Patient
    form_class = PatientForm
    # fields = ["pat","pat_sit"]
    success_message = "Le patient a été créé."

    def get_success_url(self):

        return reverse("ecrf:index")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        form.instance.pat_sai_log = self.request.user.username
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

forms.py

```
class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PatientForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields["pat"] = forms.CharField(label= "Patient", required=True)
        self.fields["pat_sit"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Site.objects.filter(sit_typ = "Site"),widget=forms.Select(), label = "Patient site")

    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ["pat","pat_sit"]
```

model.py

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    """ A class to create a Patient instance. """

    _safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE_CASCADE
    ide = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ver = models.BooleanField("Fiche verrouillée", null=True, blank=True, default=False)
    pat = models.CharField("Patient",max_length=11, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, error_messages={"unique":"Un patient avec ce code existe déjà"})
    pat_sit = models.ForeignKey("parameters.Site",on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="patient_site", db_column="pat_sit", default=4)
    # pat_dat_nai = models.DateField("Birthdate", null=True, blank=True)
    # pat_sex = models.IntegerField("Sexe", null=True, blank=True)
    pat_sai_log = models.CharField("Login de l'utilisateur ayant fait la saisie",max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    pat_sai_dat = models.DateTimeField("Date Heure de saisie", null=True, blank=True, auto_now_add=True)
    log = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:

        db_table = "crf_pat"
        verbose_name_plural = "Patients"
        ordering = ["ide"]
        permissions = [
            ("lock","can_lock_forms"),
            ("export","can_export_data"),
            ("export_patient","can_export_patient")
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.ide} - {self.pat}"
```

Comment: Are you sure you submit the form to the right view? What if you use `<form id="id-form" method="post" action="{% url 'name-of-view-for-patientcreate %}'">`?

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem you are right... have another problem now... I have edited my post

Comment: can you share the `Patient` model?

Comment: finally, I submit form using Ajax, and I have to manage error raising "manually"